# Elixir remove nested elements

Tags: enums, nested, elixir

I got a nested structure with maps and arrays and I want to keep the first elements `Enum.at(0)` of the nested arrays.
I want to keep most of the structure and replace my nested arrays with the first element of them. Lets say I have an base array `oldstruct`, this contains an array `a` which contains itself an array `b`. I want to remove all items of `a` except the first one and do the same with the array `b` which is inside `a`. In JS I would do it with this code:

```
var newStruct = [];
for (var i = 0; i < oldstruct.length; i++) {
  newStruct.push(oldStruct[i]);
  newStruct[i].a = [];
  newStruct[i].a.push(oldStruct[i].a[0]);
  newStruct[i].a[0].b = [];
  newStruct[i].a[0].b.push(oldStruct[i].a[0].b[0]);
}
```

How do I do it in Elixir?

EDIT:
This is how i wanted to solve it with Elixir:

```
result
|> Enum.filter(fn(x) ->
  Enum.filter(x.chat_users, fn(y) ->
    case y == Enum.at(x.chat_users, 0) do
      true ->
        Enum.filter(y.chat_messages, fn(z) ->
          case z == Enum.at(y.chat_messages, 0) do
            true -> true
            false -> false
          end
        end)
      false ->  false
    end
  end)
 true
end)
```

What I want:

```
[%Chat.Chat{ chat_users: [%Chat.ChatUser{
  chat_messages: [%Chat.ChatMessage{text: "some text}]}],
  {other_property: ...}},
 %Chat.Chat{ chat_users: [%Chat.ChatUser{
  chat_messages: [%Chat.ChatMessage{text: "some text}]}],
  {other_property: ...}}]
```

What I got:

```
[%Chat.Chat{ chat_users: [%Chat.ChatUser{
  chat_messages: [%Chat.ChatMessage{text: "some text},
  %Chat.ChatMessage{text: "some text},
  %Chat.ChatMessage{text: "some text}]},
  %Chat.ChatUser{
  chat_messages: [%Chat.ChatMessage{text: "some text},
  %Chat.ChatMessage{text: "some text}],
  {other_property: ...}}]},
  %Chat.Chat{ chat_users: [%Chat.ChatUser{
  chat_messages: [%Chat.ChatMessage{text: "some text},
  %Chat.ChatMessage{text: "some text},
  %Chat.ChatMessage{text: "some text}]},
  %Chat.ChatUser{
  chat_messages: [%Chat.ChatMessage{text: "some text},
  %Chat.ChatMessage{text: "some text}],
  {other_property: ...}}]}]
```

So based on my real structure: I got an chat array with some properties, an array with chatuser and an array with chat_messages per chatuser and i want to keep the first chatuser and the first chatmessage for the kept chatuser.

Solution after adapting Igor's answer:

```
|> Enum.map(fn chat ->
  Map.update!(chat, :chat_users, fn chat_users ->
    case Enum.at(chat_users, 0) do
      nil -> nil
      _ ->
        chat_user =
        chat_users
        |> List.first
        |> Map.update!(:chat_messages, & [List.first(&1)])
      [chat_user]
    end
  end)
end)
```

Comment: Can you post an example input and expected output in Elixir syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's imagine you have the following structure, which satisfies your description:

```
initial = [
  %{a: [%{b: [1,2,3]}, 1], c: 0 },
  %{a: [%{b: [1,2,3]}, 1], c: 0 },
  %{a: [%{b: [1,2,3]}, 1], c: 0 },
  %{a: [%{b: [1,2,3]}, 1], c: 0 },
]
```

And we want to have instead only first elements of the lists under the `:a` and `:b` keys.

Then the following lines in Elixir solve the problem:

```
final =
  initial
    |> Enum.map(fn map_with_a ->
      Map.update!(map_with_a, :a, fn list_with_bs ->
        map_with_b =
          list_with_bs
          |> List.first
          |> Map.update!(:b, & [List.first(&1)])
        [map_with_b]
      end)
    end)

IO.puts(inspect(final))
```

Just iterate over the lists and update the map values using [Map.update!/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#update!/3) function.

The output is:

```
[
  %{a: [%{b: [1]}], c: 0},
  %{a: [%{b: [1]}], c: 0},
  %{a: [%{b: [1]}], c: 0},
  %{a: [%{b: [1]}], c: 0}
]
```

Comment: This looks like what I want. I edited my post to provide the structure I am working on. Seems update! does the job. THX :)

Comment: And `IO.puts(inspect(final))` is new to me. I am always using inspect with label `IO.inspect(final, label: "my final result!!!")` for console output in my tests. Always good to learn new stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this set of data, similar to Igor's example:

```
initial = [
  %{a: [%{b: [1,2,3]}, 1], c: 0 },
  %{a: [%{b: [1,2,3]}, 1], c: 0 },
  %{a: [%{b: [1]}, 1], c: 0 },
  %{a: [%{b: []}, 1], c: 0 },
]
```

Another possibility is leveraging multiple function heads on the anonymous function passed to `Enum.map`, although it might be a bit less readable depending on taste:

```
Enum.map(initial, fn
    (%{a: [%{b: [h | _]} | _]} = element) -> Map.put(element, :a,  [%{b: [h]}])
    (%{a: _} = element) -> Map.put(element, :a, [])
    (element) -> element
end)

[
  %{a: [%{b: [1]}], c: 0},
  %{a: [%{b: [1]}], c: 0},
  %{a: [%{b: [1]}], c: 0},
  %{a: [], c: 0}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use-case for [`Kernel.get_and_update/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#get_and_update_in/3) with a function as a key (thanks @igor-drozdov for the initial data):

```rb
get_and_update_in(
  initial,
  [Access.all(), :a,
   fn :get_and_update, [%{b: [h|_]}|tail], _next ->
     {h, [%{b: [h]}|tail]}
   end],
  & &1)
#⇒ {[1, 1, 1, 1],
# [
#   %{a: [%{b: [1]}, 1], c: 0},
#   %{a: [%{b: [1]}, 1], c: 0},
#   %{a: [%{b: [1]}, 1], c: 0},
#   %{a: [%{b: [1]}, 1], c: 0}
# ]}
```

[`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Access.html) is very powerful and in such cases it usually obsoletes generic mappers.

Comment: Oh, never heard of `Access`. Looks really interesting. Will need some time to understand how your code works ;).  I modified the code and have `|> Enum.map(fn
  %{chat_users: [%{chat_messages: chat_messages} = first_chat_user | _rest]} = chat ->
    %{chat | chat_users: [%{first_chat_user | chat_messages: List.first(chat_messages)}]}
  other ->
    other
end)` now. Will try `Access`, because I never used it before. THX